# Core data issues on iphone

Tags: iphone

how to generate addchild method while adding data to father class for mother object

i have father class and mother class

i have created a realtionship  from father to mother

father class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Mother;

@interface Father : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Desciption;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Mother * Wife;

@end
```

in .xcdatamodel

in relation field i  have
Relation-> wife  , Destination -> Mother , inverse -> no inverse

now in main class

```
Father *fat=(Father *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Father" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
fat.Name=@"fataa";

Mother *mom = (Father*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Mother" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];


[fat addObject:mom]; // but there is no addOjbect method i think it shows by default
```

i want to add mother data in father object

Comment: got it i have to add [fat addWife:mom];   thanks sorry i was carried away

Comment: still i think i am missing something :(

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is right, you should be able to do

```
[fat addWife:mother];
```

NB Don't forget to save your changes!

```
NSError *error = nil;
[managedObject save:&error];
if (error)
    NLSog(@"Failed to save : %@", error);
```

---

Why don't you have an inverse relationship? i.e. your core data should look like :

```
// In Father
Relation-> wife , Destination -> Mother , inverse -> husband

// In Mother
Relation-> husband , Destination -> Father , inverse -> wife
```

Comment: if i set core data like you have said i am getting this error [Mother intersectsSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59534f0
2011-07-23 09:53:28.990 CoreData_rahul_saveData[594:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Mother intersectsSet:]:

Comment: and if i dont set inverse then [fat:addWife:mom] returns nil always  :(

Comment: `[fat addWife:mom]` is always going to return nil - what do you expect it to return?